# How to get comm port addresses from BIOS in QB45

Tags: basic, qbasic

I have been using the following code to get comm port addresses from BIOS in QB45:

```
PRINT "Hex addresses for ports 0 to 3 from BIOS."
DEF SEG = 0
FOR x = 0 TO 3
    z = &H400 + x * 2
    p = PEEK(z)
    q = PEEK(z + 1)
    a = q * &H100 + p
    PRINT " COM" + STR$(x); ": " + HEX$(a)
NEXT
DEF SEG
```

However when I increase FOR x = 0 to 3 into FOR x = 0 to 7 it returns x378 for 4 (which is lpt1)
and 5, 6, and 7, return 0 and I need a way to read comm ports 4, 5, 6, and 7.

I know controlpanel->devicemanager->ports can read them from resources, but I want my basic QB45
program to read them. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: The code is correct. It's runs on my PC with DOS 6.00. I can only advise you to use `STR$(x+1)` instead of `STR$(x)`... but that is not the solution of your issue!

Comment: I am using a port as 0 to 7, and a comm port as 1 to 8, that is 0-based..

Comment: I am assuming: port 4 = 3E0, port 5 = 2E0, port 6 = 338, port 7 = 238.

Comment: Usually serial cards are configurable as address and IRQ. The default settings are usually: COM1 port 3F8h - IRQ 4, COM2 port 2F8h - IRQ 3, COM3 port 3E0h - IRQ 4, COM4 port 2E0h - IRQ 3.Obviously port and IRQ can be changed with appropriate switches on the board.

Comment: I am using a fossil driver which is X00 to take care of the modem settings.

Comment: I suggest you to ask a similar question here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I contacted retrocomputing and they said the same thing: no there is no port 5-8 addresses to grab..